# Ubuntu Environment Variables for Apache

Tags: apache, variables, ubuntu, environment, lampp

I have some variables written in /etc/environment

```
NLS_DATE_FORMAT=DD/MM/YYYY
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=SPANISH
NLS_LANG=SPANISH_SPAIN.WE8ISO8859P1
```

However, when I open the shell in Ubuntu and I start lampp (**sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start**), the environment variables don't appear in phpinfo. I'm using Ubuntu 10.4

How can I make Apache2 aware of the variables?

Please help

Thank you

Comment: how about adding them to `/opt/lampp/lampp` ?

Comment: exactly where in /opt/lampp/lampp?

Comment: im guessing its a bash script? in that case after `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: You can use the `SetEnv` directive in your Apache config file if that's the only place you really need those variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried putting those variables in /etc/bash.bashrc, also in my apache config file with SetEnv. However, no luck at all. Finally I found the solution elsewhere which, in my case, it's working.

I added the variables here: **/opt/lampp/bin/envvars**

```
export NLS_DATE_FORMAT=DD/MM/YYYY
export NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=SPANISH
export NLS_LANG=SPANISH_SPAIN.WE8ISO8859P1
```

Hope this will help someone!